# Twitter API: Count number of Tweets since 0:00am this morning?

Tags: javascript, twitter, numbers, posts, tweets

Is there an API to count the number of Tweets since 0:00am this morning for a particular user? I have tried the following Javascript but the closest I can get to it is the total number of tweets for all time for that user.

```
$.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/BarackObama.json?count=1&include_rts=1&callback=?", function(data) {
     $("#twitter").html(data[0].user.statuses_count);
});
```

Comment: Do you care about time zones?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be the number of tweets made today. So this should ideally be from midnight. But from 6:00am would also be suitable too I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the user timeline until you get tweets which were posted "yesterday" (i.e. before 0:00am). Once you get it, you just have to count tweets which were posted "today" (i.e. after 0:00am).

**EDIT 1** : a pseudo JavaScript code for getting it

```
var howManyTweetsWerePostedToday = function () {
    var timeline = downloadTimeline()
    var lastTweet = timeline[timeline.length-1]
    var now = new Date()
    var today = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDay(), 0, 0, 0, 0) // Limit between today and yesterday
    var lastTweetDate = new Date(lastTweet["created_at"])

    while (lastTweetDate.getTime() >= today.getTime()) {
        var lastTweetID = lastTweet["id_str"]
        var earlierTweetsTimeline = downloadTimeline(max_id = lastTweetID)
        timeline = timeline.concat(earlierTweetsTimeline.shift())
        lastTweet = timeline[timeline.length-1]
        lastTweetDate = new Date(lastTweet["created_at"])
    }

    return getNumberOfTweetsThatWerePostedTodayInTheTimeline(timeline)
}();
```

With `downloadTimeline()` which is a function calling the `GET statuses/user_timeline`Twitter API endpoint to get the timeline. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline for details about the endpoint, especially `max_id` which is the highest tweet ID that will be in the results.

`created_at` is the date when a tweet was posted. `id_str` is the ID of a tweet under a String form. See https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets for more details about tweets.

Comment: Great, thanks air-dex. How do I stop downloading the timeline when it gets to "yesterday"? Im finding the twitter documentations really inacessible. Can you point me in the right direction? Is this a modification of the js script I am currently using?

Comment: See the edit 1 for that. For the JS code I do my best with my little JavaScript knowledge (I don't know anything about jQuery).